# making sure that EIP is not reused across VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, elastic-ip, aws-cloudformation

Given:
One (ore more) elastic IPs that we want to reuse. (the ip pool)
A CloudFormation template with a machine that has an elastic ip associated to it. (via AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation)
Bringing up / tearing down multiple CloudFormation stacks that get ips from the shared EIP pool. (the ip is a parameter in the stack and is computed before the the stack is launched)

My expectations were that if one VPC / CloudFormation stack is already using an EIP, other attempts to use it would fail.
It turns out that if you attempt to use the same EIP in another stack, it will work. The EIP will be bound to the latest stack that is created.

To make it ever worse, if say stack 1 uses an EIP, stack 2 uses the same EIP, if you tear down stack 1 after stack 2 is in use an 'stole' the IP, stack 2 will lose the IP (resulting in the IP being free - i.e. not bound to any instance).

Has anyone run across this issue? How do you ensure that you're not running in situations above?

The reason I have to use the ips is that they are whitelisted for access in a system I'm interacting with over the public internet. The traffic must come from the IPs in that pool and cannot just grab any random public ip.

Comment: Wouldn't routing the outbound traffic through a NAT instance with an EIP be a lot more straightforward?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the instance I'm talking about is a NAT :) Left it out to keep it simple but yeah I'm going through a NAT instance.

Comment: lol, well, in that case, my question rewrites itself to ask whether it wouldn't be simpler to just leave the NAT instance running? t2.micro makes an excellent and very inexpensive NAT machine.  But here's a thought: when an EIP is manually associated in the console, there is the option to "allow reassociation."  If not selected, you [can't steal the EIP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateAddress.html).  A cursory read of the CloudFormation docs suggests that there is no comparable capability there when doing an association.

Comment: well... ideally this would be available through the API. leaving the t2.micro running is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attaching the EIP directly to the instance, attach an ENI that has the EIP attached to it. If the ENI is in-use, it wont be detached from the instance it is currently attached to.

Comment: i'm not sure I follow. can you please explain why this would be better than just using the EIP?

Comment: If your goal is to effectively "reserve an eip" for an instance and not have it detach when you bring up another instance, a way to do that is to add a level of abstraction: associate the EIP to an Elastic Network Interface and make _that_ what you attach to your instance to effectively give it the EIP that you want. You will not lose the EIP like you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% if what you want is possible through cloudformation. But personally I would be doing it a different way. Cloudformation is great at what it does but when you want to start adding logic and conditions it struggles.

Create all your instances as usual but don't try and bind an eip, instead use a user data script and the aws cli to search for an unattached eip and attach it. Doing it with the cli will give you much more power.

Good Luck

Comment: interesting idea. I do have a script that runs and generates the template. I guess this will minimize the window in which things can go wrong and will take the EIP binding out of cloud formation, but it's less than ideal...